# Understanding the basics of form in HTML

Tags: html

HTML 1:

```
<html>
<body>

<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>   
</body>
</html>
```

HTML 2:

```
<html>
<body>

<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
<input type="email" value="email">
</body>
</html>
```

I know that `<form>` element is used to collect the user input and pass it to the specific url. In the HTML 1 when the submit button is selected the data inside the `<form>` element is collected and passed to the url mentioned.

I have same code in the HTML 2 but I have included another `<input>` element outside the `<form>` element.

So, my doubt is that when the submit button is selected in the HTML 2 what will happen to the `<input>` element outside the `<form>`, will the value entered be read or not? If yes or no what is the reason, because if my understanding is correct `submit` is inside the `<form>` element so it will read the values inside the `<form>` and ignore the `<input>` element placed outside. If I'm wrong please correct me, also please explain.

Comment: You know, you could just try it and see...

Comment: This isn't a tutorial site. There are lots of those available; you can find one through Google. And you can try things yourself to see if they work or not, you know.

Comment: I tried it using jquery, when submit is selected , value of the `<input>` outside the `<form>` is read. So I got this doubt

Comment: @KenWhite I tried to google it but couldn't find the appropriate or convincing answer.

Comment: You could start with [the basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms), like, say, [the standard that defines how forms work in HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html).

Answer (score 1):

When you submit the html `form` the inputs inside the tag form will be sents to the url in the action attribute of the form and the input that are outside of the form will be ignored because he are not in the same environment/context.

Some docs about `form` tag [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The input value outside the form will not be read because it is *outside* the form. The form encompasses only the elements inside the `<form>` and `</form>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

The values outside the form tag won't be read.
HTML is a Markup Language which works based on parent child tags/nodes. So this necessary as there can be multiple forms and many input fields nested in the same file.

**JQuery**
If using jquery, please use an id for the form tag and use it to read the fields